# Difference between Threat and Menace

Tags: expressions, synonyms, jokes

I was reading a technical blog [post](http://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2015/02/assert_called_once-threat-or-menace.html), and the post subtitle is: **assert_called_once: Threat or Menace**

I do not understood what the writer wanted to express with this synonyms. I mean, is there a popular (regional) joke with this words or just a pun?

And there is difference or particular in use of them?

Comment: I'd never heard of this, but google brings up this wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threat_or_menace

Comment: It's a "nerd-talk" :)

Comment: @Sarah post research as an answer ;-)

Comment: I wouldn't have picked up on that either, but Sarah got it, it's clearly meant as humor.

Comment: @MauroBaraldi If you have found a **satisfactory answer to your question**, please **mark it as answered** so people looking for truly unanswered questions will not waste their time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you got this from a blog on **Python unit testing** [here](http://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2015/02/assert_called_once-threat-or-menace.html)

The problem with the test seems to be that the test will **pass** when in reality it **should not**

The blog is about **Test Driven Development** where the test suite is used to ensure the underlying code is doing what it's supposed to do. **TDD** is more a feature of **Ruby** and **Rails** and is becoming more adapted for **Python**.

The fact that the title was named **Threat or Menace** is the directed towards the test itself:

> **assert_called_once**

when the actual test is supposed to be

> **assert_called_once_with**

which is the method supplied by **Python Mock Library** for server testing (in this case). However, the misspelling can still cause the test to **pass** even though there is a typo.

**Which is not the best thing to happen**

These oddities can happen when **monkey patching** is involved which seems to be the case.

[NB: I am not a Python person]

Comment: To have an answer from 2 doubts, from different categories, in only one post. Thank you Stack Exchange for make it possible!